# Result of running `restart ipsec-key-management`

Tags: juniper, ipsec, srx

I have Juniper SRX 1400 which is used mainly for IPSEC tunnels. And now I facing a bug in firmware with ID PR1085657 (*IKE doesn't come up when the SRX is the initiator*). Possible solutions to this is to issue command `restart ipsec-key-management` or reboot the device. As this is only one device and I don't have a backup for it, I'm looking for first variant - is to restart key management.

I've googled a bit and didn't find anything about what services exactly affected by this restart. Is it only IKE? Or IKE and IPSEC? Will all active IPSEC connections be disconnected at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was [found](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/possible-to-restart-dynamic-VPN-services/m-p/31705) on Juniper forums and it states, quote:

> This will restart the entire IPSec process.

So, answering my question - all IPSEC connections will be terminated.